# Is the treatment of Jar Jar Binks in Aftermath: Empire's End a reflection of audience treatment?

Tags: character-analysis, inspiration, star-wars, chuck-wendig

In one of the [Interlude scenes](https://archive.org/details/starwarsaftermat0000wend_k3a1/page/94/mode/2up) in the book *Star Wars Aftermath: Empire's End*, a child interacts with Jar Jar Binks, and gives more details about how the adults don't like him due to their beliefs that he helped the Empire come into being.  However, the kids love him because he's a funny clown.

> Since children started coming in by the shipload as refugees, the Gungan  has served them, performing for the kids once or twice a day. He does tricks. He juggles. He falls over and shakes his head as his eyes roll around inside their fleshy stalks. He makes goofy sounds and does strange little dances. . . .
>
> The clown, they call him. *Bring the clown. We want to see the clown. . . .*
>
> That's what the kids say.
>
> The adults, though. They don't say much about him. Or *to* him. And no other Gungans come to see him, either. Nobody even says his name.

Is this a reflection of how real life audiences saw the character?  Children liked him for being goofy, but adult fans really didn't like him.

Comment: This is actually a really good question about an SFF-type book while adding the literary element. Is this what you were talking about when you said, "literary questions", @Emrakul?

Comment: @Benjamin I definitely think this counts as one, yeah. I like this question quite a bit.

Comment: Adults don't like him, but it has nothing to do with the Empire. It's because the character was weak comic relief, dumb without being entertaining, and borderline racist to boot. As for whether kids like him... I have no idea, but I don't think he numbers up there with the great comic relief sidekicks like Olaf in Frozen.

Comment: @JoshuaEngel   Unlike the Ewoks, which the adults who rejected Jar Jar, embraced when they themselves were kids.  (I'm being sarcastic about the Ewoks being different from Jar Jar in terms of silliness and borderline racism, should one choose that analytic path.)

Comment: I was 12 (?) when I first saw Jar Jar Binks and hated him, and my friends at the time also thought he was terrible, so...I dunno if kids loved him.

Comment: Is there an in-canon explanation that people just find Jar-Jar annoying? Qui-Gon Jinn certainly seems fed up with him at points.